# How to selectively set values to a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, data-cleaning

I have a large dataframes that I'm cleaning up with a rough schema shown below:

```
| point_id | traj_id | col 0 | col n |
|----------|---------|-------|-------|
| 0        | a       |  val  |  val  |
| 1        | a       |  val  |  val  |
| 0        | b       |  val  |  val  |
```

the dataframe has 24 million rows and 11 columns.
As you can see one point can belong to 2 trajectories and this is leading to a large amount of redundancy in my dataframe, with only 15 million unique points.

I want to reduce the redundancy by assigning each point with 2 traj_id values based on what trajectories it belongs to, giving me a table with the below structure:

```
| point_id | traj_id_1 | traj_id_2 | col 0 | col n |
|----------|-----------|-----------|-------|-------|
| 0        | a         | b         |  val  |  val  |
| 1        | a         | NaN       |  val  |  val  |
```

where if a point belongs to only one trajectory traj_id2 will be set to nan.

How could I go about doing this efficiently? cuz when i tried to iteratively append to a list my system ran out of memory.

- Note that for 2 rows with the same point id all columns except traj_id have the same values so they can be considered as the same point.

Answer (score 0):

```
# create traj_id column using assign, by grouping on point_id and taking cumcount
# pivot to reorient the data

(df.assign(id='traj_id_'  +  # create a id column for pivot
           (df.groupby('point_id')['point_id'].cumcount()+1).astype(str)  )  # take cumcount of points
 .pivot( # re-orient the data
     index=['point_id','col_0','col_n'], 
     columns='id', 
     values='traj_id')
).reset_index()
```

```
id  point_id    col_0   col_n   traj_id_1   traj_id_2
0          0      val     val           a        b
1          1      val     val           a       NaN
```

Comment: This is very close to what i need however its not merging the 2 points as shown in your example.

Comment: Solution was based on the text data you posted and resulted in expected output. Post the data as a code and I can try again. Furthermore, is any of your data of category type? If so add observed=True in group by. Let me know